# 'Assertion Error' with plot_model() in Colaboratory

Tags: python

I have a problem with the function plot_model() in phyton. I'm a novice with the Keras and Tensorflow world. The function returns me only an 'Assertion Error' with no other explanation. I've search everywhere, but I've not find anything.
If I try to import 'pyplot', it tells me that the package wasn't installated, but I've already installated the 'matplotlib' package.
I use Colaboratory.

EDIT: I put 'import matplotlib.pyplot' but the Assertion Error remains. It give me the error when it calls ' assert dot.get_node(inbound_layer_id)'

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Dropout, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 15, 32
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 7352, 128, 9
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=( 
n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
#classificazione delle features estratte: 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')) 
#tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, 
write_images=False)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, 
show_layer_names=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to execute plot\_model in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681910/unable-to-execute-plot-model-in-keras)

Comment: @dm2 nothing, it give me the same error, but underline the specific point of the error only..

Comment: just to clarify, importing everything from `tensroflow.keras.models` and `tensoflow.keras.layers` instead of `keras.models` and `keras.layers` doesn't fix the problem?

Comment: I've tried with tensorflow.keras instead of keras. and it works!!! Thanks! @dm2